# Incorporating a custom iOS plugin with NativeScript

Tags: cocoapods, nativescript

I've been following along with the [NativeScript tutorial for building plugins that use CocoaPods](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods).  I created a test framework in Xcode [using this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios).

Here is my directory structure:

```
├── KnobControl
│   ├── KnobControl
│   ├── KnobControl.podspec
│   └── KnobControl.xcodeproj
├── MYCocoaPodsApp
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── app
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── platforms
│   │   └── ios
│   │       ├── MYCocoaPodsApp
│   │       ├── MYCocoaPodsApp.xcodeproj
│   │       └── Podfile
│   └── webpack.config.js
└── my-plugin
    ├── package.json
    └── platforms
        └── ios
            └── Podfile
```

Here is what's in `KnobControl/KnobControl.podspec`

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name          = "KnobControl"
    spec.version       = "1.0.0"
    spec.summary       = "A knob control like UISlider, but in circular form"
    spec.description   = "The knob control is a completely customizable widget that can be used in any iOS app. It also plays a little victory fanfare."
    spec.homepage      = "http://raywenderlich.com"
    spec.license       = "MIT"
    spec.author        = { "Me" => "my@email.address" }
    spec.platform      = :ios, "12.1"
    spec.source        = { :path => '.' }
    spec.source_files  = "KnobControl"
    spec.swift_version = "4.2"
end
```

Here is what's in `my-plugin/platforms/ios/Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '12.1'
pod 'KnobControl', :path => '../../../KnobControl'
```

Here is what's in `MYCocoaPodsApp/platforms/ios/Podfile` after running `tns-build ios`:

```
use_frameworks!

target "MYCocoaPodsApp" do
# Begin Podfile - /MYCocoaPodsApp/node_modules/my-plugin/platforms/ios/Podfile
platform :ios, '12.1'
pod 'KnobControl', :path => '../../../KnobControl'

# End Podfile
end
```

When I run `tns build ios` I get the following error:

```
Building project...
Xcode build...
warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for your deployment target (iOS 12.1). You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the i386 architecture. (in target 'KnobControl')
warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for your deployment target (iOS 12.1). You should update your ARCHS build setting to remove the i386 architecture. (in target 'Pods-MYCocoaPodsApp')
<unknown>:0: error: iOS 12 does not support 32-bit programs
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
** BUILD FAILED **

Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: It seems that the pod is setting deployment target and you are dealing with this issue https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4197#issuecomment-444030877 - try the provided solution (the fix for this issue is upcoming)

Comment: @NickIliev That worked.  Thanks!